# How to make HTACCESS URL with getting other variabel PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I get problem while implement .htaccess file,

for general htaccess like : sitename.com/id/other_var its working very well to getting $_GET Request,

```
RewriteRule ^sitename.com/id/other_var$ index.php?id=$1&othervar=$2 [L]
```

my problem is, I need to implement like : sitename.com/id/other?a=x&b=y ,

how it work on htaccess ?

thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Mod Rewrite can use simple regex statements to achieve this..

```
RewriteRule ^sitename.com/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&othervar=$2 [L]
```

The above would pass an integer value for id and allow anything passed for othervar